# Color change when saving as PDF from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, pdf

This a flower which I created using a watercolour brush in Illustrator:

[image]

But when I saved it as a PDF, the colour changes like below:

[image]

Comment: What are your color settings and what PDF settings are you using? I assume you're converting so some other color space/profile (Also, I assume you're talking about the actual flower rather than the background?)

Comment: Surely the PDF isn't randomly adding that blue and green background. Do those change the appearance in Illustrator? I.E. if the flower pedals have transparency in them... that blue background would show through.

Comment: Maybe you can provide link to the source .ai file?

Answer (score -1):

There could be a few things causing this.

As mentioned above, your colour profile you are using.
Quality of the PDF
PDF viewer
There seems to be a lot of texture in the petals, is PDF best?  Can you not use a hi-res jpeg?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't that  be better an comment?

Comment: Hi Kurt, it won't let me comment on his questions, only an answer. I'm happy for you  to copy and paste it as a comment yourself, and then I can delete my answer.